# How do I read a .txt file from my One Drive Documents folder with Python?

Tags: python, onedrive

I have registered the app, added read-write permissions on it, gotten admin consent, and gotten the token. When I make a GET request I get an error.

This my Python code:

```
import requests, sys, os, json

# Get token
params = {
    'client_id': clientID,
    'scope': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default', 
    'client_secret': clientSecret,
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
 }

response = requests.post('https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token', data=params)
jresp = response.json()
access_token = jresp['access_token']

# Get item
header = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token}
response = requests.get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/Documents/WildRydes.txt', headers = header)
print response
print response.text
print response.content
sys.exit()
```

This is what is returned:

```
<Response [500]>
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Unable to retrieve user's mysite URL.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": ,
      "date": "2020-04-29T12:42:06"
    }
  }
}
```

I have been following the Microsoft Graph API documentation for the past two days straight. They are very good at theory but rubbish at showing concrete examples. Or maybe they're good at hiding where those are.

Comment: Did you try adding :/content at the end of file path/name >>> response = requests.get('XXXXgraph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/Documents/WildRydes.txt:/content', headers = header)

Comment: Also, did you looking into using their SDK or looking at their examples here: https://github.com/onedrive/onedrive-sdk-python?

Comment: Just tried now and it didn't work. Got the same error. Also this does not work either: response = requests.get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive', headers = header)

Comment: Yeah I looked at onedrivesdk yesterday but after 30 minutes of not being able to install the module I gave up on it and decided to use requests instead.